# PHP Query Array variable to JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, getjson, json

I am learning to pass data, retrieved from MySQL via PHP, to an HTML form using jQuery.

The php file returns all data in two array variables:  `$resultsa` and `$resultsb`

Please feel free to correct my approach - I am using `.getjson` query (but failing) to collect the data and store it in a JavaScript variable.

```
// retrievedata.php
<?php
    include('/include/connection.php');

    if (isset($getid))
    {
        $getid = $_GET['getid'];
    }
    $resultsa = array();
    $resultsb = array();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM FB_FoodBrew");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $resultsa[] = $row['Food_Name'];
        $resultsb[] = $row['Drink_Varietal'];
    }

    echo json_encode(array_values($resultsa));
    echo json_encode(array_values($resultsb));
```

The javascript is pasted in the  portion of the HTML page here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/flex-slider/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.getJSON('page.php', function(data) {
            // assuming data is an array
            Array.forEach(function(item) {
                console.log(item);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Unfortunately, my experience with javascript is very limited, and I'm having a very difficult time determining where this script should go, which variables should be used, etc.

Comment: You probably looked at it already: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
it gives some examples on how to print some data

Answer (score 0):

You're saying:

```
$.getJSON('page.php', function(data)
```

But the page is not named page.php, it's retrievedata.php.
So it's looking for the output of page.php but can't find any!

Comment: I wish!  This is just generic code representing what I'm trying to do.